# Poor Man's GNU Parallel implemented in ksh?

Tags: ksh, gnu, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I'd like to use the feature of [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) where it can execute the command and the list it's fed in parallel and spit it out after it's all done, however, I don't want to install GNU parallel across all of our servers.

Or perhaps a parallel version of `xargs`?

Is there a ksh implementation of what GNU Parallel does? In this case, it doesn't have to be done in order as GNU Parallel does -- just as long as all the output can be piped or stored. I'd also like to avoid using temporary files.

Comment: GNU Parallel is a single perl script. I am curious why you prefer installing a ksh script over installing a single perl script that is designed to have very few dependencies. Can you elaborate on that? (Disclosure: I am the author of GNU Parallel)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to parallelize on a machine with multiple cores, you can just use (GNU) `xargs`, e.g.:

```
echo seq_[0-9][0-9].gz | xargs -n 1 -P 16 ./crunching
```

Meaning: `xargs` starts up to 16 processes in parallel of `./crunching` using 1 token from stdin for each process.

You can also use `split` in combination with xargs.

Or you can create a simple Makefile for Job execution and call `make -f mymf -j $CORES` (you need temporary files for this solution).

**PS:** The GNU parallel manual also includes some comparisons with other tools, including [xargs](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_xargs_and_gnu_parallel) and [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_make__j_and_gnu_parallel), interestingly they write:

> (Very early versions of GNU parallel were coincidently implemented using make -j).

Comment: It is important for the asker that "all the output can be piped or stored". `xargs` is notoriously bad at that when run in parallel because the output can mix.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: I agree with your answer 100%, I always just use xargs.  Many people just don't know GNU xargs is able to do parallel!

Answer (score 1):

Look at `parallel --embed` which embeds GNU Parallel into the same shell script that you use it from.

```
parallel --embed > new_script
```

then edit new_script.