# Batch up a number of jobs to run concurrently

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Four tasks in parallel… how do I do that?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35416/four-tasks-in-parallel-how-do-i-do-that)

I have a group of jobs to run (a few hundred jobs) - they have a variety of command names and parameters. Each one runs anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours (and I don't really know which ones will run longer than others until I run them).

They are pretty much CPU bound, but some do significant I/O, so I want to run 4 at a time (one per CPU core).

Is there already a simple command to do this? Something like *runbatch -n 4 filename* that will read the file and execute n jobs at a time until it's done.  Since some of the command lines  have special characters and spaces in parameters, using *xargs -P* to run them under *bash -c*  seems a little problematic to get everything escaped properly.

I've thought about just building a makefile and using *make -j* or building a simple Perl job scheduler that runs jobs in the background and dispatches a new one as each one finishes, but wanted to see if there was a more elegant solution that already exists?

Comment: Ahh yes, looks like you're right - it looks like Gnu Parallel will do what I want. I'll give it a shot and will also take a look at pexec