# Bash wait for jobs and limit job count

Tags: bash, job-control, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Four tasks in parallel… how do I do that?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35416/four-tasks-in-parallel-how-do-i-do-that)

Suppose a loop invoking a command

```
 grep -v '#' < files.m3u | sed 's/\\\\/\/\//g' | sed 's/\\/\//g' | while read line
 do
    filename=$(basename "$line")
    avconv -i "$line" "${filename%.*}.wav"
 done
```

Putting & after avconv will keep spawning avconv for each file. Now I want to do two things:

- I want to limit the number of processes spawned to 4
- When the loop is done I want to wait for the last one to be ready

Answer (score 3):

You can remember the PID of each new child (check `$!` after starting it). Periodically check how many children still exist (e.g. by `kill -0`), if the number goes down, spawn a new one, etc. At the end, just `wait`.

Here is a script I wrote for the same reason:

```
#! /bin/bash

## Tries to run commands in parallel. Commands are read from STDIN one
## per line, or from a given file specified by -f.
## Author: E. Choroba

file='-'
proc_num=$(grep -c ^processor'\b' /proc/cpuinfo)
prefix=$HOSTNAME-$USER-$$
sleep=10

children=()
names=()

if [[ $1 =~ ^--?h(elp)?$ ]] ; then
    cat <<-HELP
    Usage: ${0##*/} [-f file] [-n max-processes] [-p tmp-prefix] -s [sleep]
      Defaults:
        STDIN for file
        $proc_num for max-processes (number of processors)
        $prefix for tmp-prefix
        $sleep for sleep interval
    HELP
    exit
fi

function debug () {
    if ((DEBUG)) ; then
        echo "$@" >&2
    fi
}

function child_count () {
    debug Entering child_count "${children[@]}"
    child_count=0
    new_children=()
    for child in "${children[@]}" ; do
        debug Trying $child
        if kill -0 $child 2>/dev/null ; then
            debug ... exists
            let child_count++
            new_children+=($child)
        fi
    done

    children=("${new_children[@]}")
    echo $child_count
    debug Leaving child_count "${children[@]}"
}

while getopts 'f:n:p:s:' arg ; do
    case $arg in
        f ) file=$OPTARG ;;
        n ) proc_num=$((OPTARG)) ;;
        p ) prefix=$OPTARG;;
        s ) sleep=$OPTARG;;
        * ) echo "Warning: unknown option $arg" >&2 ;;
    esac
done

i=0
while read -r line ; do
    debug Reading $line
    name=$prefix.$i
    let i++
    names+=($name)

    while ((`child_count`>=proc_num)) ; do
        sleep $sleep
        debug Sleeping
    done

    eval $line 2>$name.e >$name.o &
    children+=($!)
    debug Running "${children[@]}"
done < <(cat $file)

debug Loop ended
wait
cat "${names[@]/%/.o}"
cat "${names[@]/%/.e}" >&2
rm "${names[@]/%/.o}" "${names[@]/%/.e}"
```

Comment: Beware the race conditions that come with the approach of "checking if a process is alive by PID".  There is no good way to detect the case where the process exits and its PID gets recycled for a new process.  A lock file in a secure directory that the child removes on exit would be more robust.  In the end, I'd just say don't reinvent the wheel (unless your wheel is really better).

Answer (score 2):

From the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35416/9537), tailored to your variation:

```
sed -n -e '/#/!s,\\,/,g' files.m3u | xargs -d '\n' -I {} -P 4 \
    sh -c 'line=$1; file=${line##*/}; avconv -i "$line" "${file%.*}.wav"' avconv_sh {}
```

Again, GNU `xargs` or some version supporting `-d` and `-P` is required.  Also beware of extra spaces in the input file at the beginning and end of the line - this snippet will keep them in if they exist, which may cause problems.

Comment: yes, xargs' parallel execution option is perfect for this.  it's (unfortunately) a little-known feature of GNU xargs.  Here are some useful links describing the feature: http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20100418_235041 and http://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20090304/index.html

Comment: GNU `parallel` (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is also a useful tool for this kind of job.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way. Thanks for the $! tips

```
#!/bin/bash
children[0]=0
children[1]=0
children[2]=0
children[3]=0

i=0
grep -v '#' < files.m3u | sed 's/\\\\/\/\//g' | sed 's/\\/\//g' | while read line
do
    filename=$(basename "$line")
    let k="$i%4"
    wait ${children[k]}
    avconv -i "$line" "${filename%.*}.wav" &
    children[k]=$!
    let i++
done

wait ${children[0]}
wait ${children[1]}
wait ${children[2]}
wait ${children[3]}
```

Comment: Your solution is far from optimal. While you are waiting for job 1, jobs 2, 3 and 4 might have finished...

Comment: Yes, but the will be approximatly equal in size so it should not differ that much in my case.