# How to limit the number of background process in Unix

Tags: shell-script, background-process, nohup

I have to run a script in 100 parts while making sure that only 10 parts run at parallel at any point of time.

Below script will trigger all the 100 processes at the same time :-

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    nohup ksh my_background_script.ksh -mod ${i} &
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two tools commonly used for this, `xargs` and GNU `parallel`:

1. `xargs` is older, very often installed by default, but more limited. You would use it like this:

   ```
    seq 1 100 | xargs -P 10 -I {} nohup ksh my_background_script.ksh -mod {} &
   ```

   The `-P 10` is telling it to run 10 processes in parallel.
2. GNU `parallel`, which although not installed by default on many systems, should be readily available for any GNU/Linux system and is far more powerful than `xargs`. You would use it like this (probably, the details depend on what you are running):

   ```
    parallel -j 10 nohup ksh my_background_script.ksh -mod ::: {1..100}
   ```

Some more details on the two programs and their respective uses can be found here: [GNU parallel vs & (I mean background) vs xargs -P](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104778/22222)