# Is there a way to run process parallelly in the loop of a bash script

Tags: bash, parallelism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parallelizing a for loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/parallelizing-a-for-loop)

The original code might look like this:

```
 for i in *; do something.py $i; done
```

I was wondering whether I can run these jobs parallelly in the backgroud, such as:

```
 for i in *; do something.py $i &; done
```

I tried and found the `&` here won't work..

Moreover, a better way might be that bash allow 8 jobs(or any number) run together **in the queue in background**, but I don't know how to do that...

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: I would just do this in Python, anyway.

Comment: Not very much a duplicate, that one doesn't concern the problem with `&` though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove the `;` character, so in final :

```
 for i in *; do something.py $i & done
```

And for running *N* instance of your script at the same time, see `man 1 parallel`

See http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: Added some hints about `parallel`

Comment: It isn't necessary to comment after editing a post: its a wiki, the edit history is recorded...

Comment: Interesting, you don't need the semicolon before `done`

Comment: `&` is a command terminator like `;` and newline: also `&&` and `||`. See SHELL GRAMMAR in the bash manpage, or [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)